# Rails another encoding hell in emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, encoding

I have already struggled with some UTF8 encoding issues over the past, but this time it's about a html email template being processed.

For some reason I ignore, Rails tries to parse the `.html.erb` email file as ASCII 8-BIT, and therefore I cannot add variables that contain UTF8 chars

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8):
    1: <h1>Bonjour <%= @first_name %>,</h1>
```

(When the first name is michaël with an ë)

I have already used several tricks, like adding

*config/environment.rb*

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

*config/application.rb*

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Using a stupid Debian 6 linux production server / Ruby 2.0.0p353. Everything works FINE on a local dev installation with Windows, what a joke...

What can I do to force loading the html email view with UTF-8 ?

Comment: Are you sure it's the template that has encoding ASCII-8-bit and not @first_name ?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but if it was the other way around, wouldn't it be `UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT` ?

Comment: I've no idea. It takes 5 seconds to check @first_name.encoding

Comment: Yeah tried to do that, not that simple because it's on a production server. Turns out it doesn't print it. I'll try something else...

Comment: Okay yeah, turns out that info comes from a LDAP, and it is ASCII 8 bit encoded... I thought mongoid/active-record would handle writing back values to the DB as utf8 though with the config settings =_=

Comment: Thanks, so that actually fixed the problem... But then I wonder if there's a way to ensure all the strings that are written to the DB be converted to utf8 ?